# Python script cannot find zmq module

Tags: python, zeromq, redhat, python-2.6

I am using Python 2.6.6 and RedHat Linux version 7.  I installed ZeroMQ by running these commands *as root*:

```
tar -xvf zeromq-4.0.5.tar.gz    
cd zeromq-4.0.5    
./configure    
make    
make install    
ldconfig    
yum install python-devel    
easy_install pyzmq
```

When I try to run foo.py I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "foo.py", line 7, in
>   
>       import zmq ImportError: No module named zmq

How do I get the module zmq installed?  `pip install pyzmq` indicates that the requirement has already been satisfied.  `python -v foo.py` didn't show me anything meaningful.

Comment: https://blog.serverdensity.com/building-zeromq-and-pyzmq-on-red-hat/ any help?

Comment: The obivous questions: is easy_install the one associated with the python-interpreter you get at typing "python"?  what's the output of easy_install pyzmp? Can you locate the pyzmq-files on your harddrive?

Comment: First question, I don't know.  I ran this: whereis easy_install  I saw this:
easy_install: /usr/bin/easy_install /usr/local/bin/easy_install  
Second question:  I'm assuming you meant pyzmq  easy_install pyzmq
Searching for pyzmq
Best match: pyzmq 14.5.0
Processing pyzmq-14.5.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
pyzmq 14.5.0 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyzmq-14.5.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
Processing dependencies for pyzmq
Finished processing dependencies for pyzmq        Third question: Yes.